# como hacer update de varias lineas con foreach?

Tags: php

estoy haciendo update de inputs dinamicos que tienen valores inseridos desde una consulta del DB. De la forma que lo he intentado me apresenta un erro:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rumos\update.php on line 23

```
**pagina donde esta el formulario**

<?php

                  @$id = $_GET['passageiro'];


                $sql= "SELECT * FROM clienteseat WHERE  id_cliente='$id' ";
                $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);


                  //$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                $i = 1;
                  while( $i <= 10 & $row =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { 



                  echo '
                  <li id="passageiro0'.$i.'" class="ui-widget-content passageiro"><strong class="ui-selectee"> '.$row['passageiros_nome'].'</strong> 
                  <br>

                       Assento: <span id="assento" >Escolha um assento</span>

                  <input  class="id_cliente2" name="id[]" value="'.$row['id_cliente2'].'" type="view">
                  <input class="InputPassageiro"  id="3770" name="seatPassageiro[]" type="view" value="0"  /> 

                  <br>
                    <a class="removerAssento ui-selectee" href="#">Remover Assento Selecionado</a>

                  </li> 


                  ';
                 $i++;
                    }


                ?>
```

**Pagina para update.php**

```
  if(!empty($_POST))

  { 
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $contrato = $_POST['contrato'];
   $seatPassageiro = $_POST['seatPassageiro'];




   foreach($seatPassageiro as $seatPassageiro )
  {
```

**esta es la parte del codigo que aparece el error**

```
     $sql = "UPDATE cliente2 SET  seatPassageiro='$seatPassageiro' WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

 }



 }//empty post
```

Ya he buscado informacion para esse erro pero todavia no he conseguido resolverlo.

A quien pueda hecharme una mano, gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que el problema viene de la sintaxis del `foreach`. Estás usando el mismo nombre de variable para el `array` que para la variable que tendrá el valor en cada iteración. Deberían ser distintos: `foreach ($seatPassageiro as $passageiro) { ... }`

Comment: @ phpMyGuel. Todavia apresenta el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Puedes volver a añadir el comentario? El problema lo tenías en el "VALUES (`$seatPassageiro`)'" que usabas en otra sentencia que habías puesto en él.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que no estés poniendo bien la variable en la sentencia sql:

```
$sql = "UPDATE cliente2 SET seatPassageiro = '".$seatPassageiro."' WHERE id = '".$id."' ";
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, lo he conseguido combiando algunas partes del codigo tanto del formulario cuanto del update.

**formulario html**

> ```
> input class="InputPassageiro"  id="3770" name="seatPassageiro['.$row['id_cliente2'].']" type="hidden" value="0"  />
> ```

**update.php**

> ```
> foreach($_POST['seatPassageiro'] as $id_cliente2=> $seatPassageiro)
>  {
>      if($seatPassageiro !==''){
>      $sql= " UPDATE  cliente2 SET seatPassageiro= '$seatPassageiro' WHERE id_cliente2= '$id_cliente2'";
>     $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
>     }
>  }
> ```